# python calculator

Tags: python

I found this calculator code in the web.

I want to add some function, like the pow() but it returns an error.

The error:

> button(powF, LEFT, 'pow', lambda w=display: w.set(w.pow()))
>
> AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute 'pow'

---

```
from Tkinter import * 
import math

def frame(root, side):
   w = Frame(root)
   w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
   return w

def button(root, side, text, command=None):
   w = Button(root, text=text, command=command)
   w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
   return w

class Calculator(Frame):
   def __init__(self):
       Frame.__init__(self)
       self.option_add('*Font', 'Verdana 20 bold') 
       self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)  
       self.master.title('tk') 
       self.master.iconname("calcu1ator") 

       display = StringVar()
     Entry(self,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=display).pack(side=TOP,expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
   
       for key in ("123", "456", "789", "-0."):
           keyF = frame(self, TOP)
       
           for char in key:
               button(keyF, LEFT, char,lambda w=display, c=char: w.set(w.get() + c))
           
       opsF = frame(self, TOP)
   
       for char in "+-*/=":
           if char == '=':
               btn = button(opsF, LEFT, char)
               btn.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e, s=self, w=display: s.calc(w), '+')
           else:
               btn = button(opsF, LEFT, char,lambda w=display, s=' %s '%char:w.set(w.get()+s))

       clearF = frame(self, BOTTOM)
       button(clearF, LEFT, 'Clr', lambda w=display: w.set(''))
   
       #powF = frame(self, BOTTOM)
       #button(powF, LEFT, 'pow', lambda w=display: pow(w,2))

   def calc(self, display):
       try:
           display.set(eval(display.get()))
       except:
           display.set("ERROR")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Calculator().mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the error?  Help us help you.  Don't make people read your code to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: wherever you got this code from, its bad, using `eval` is not good. ever.

Comment: @InbarRose -- `eval` exists for a reason.  Guido has never backed down from removing/changing the language to remove unnecessary stuff -- Thus, Guido at least still believes that `eval` has a place in the language (I do to).  However, you're definitely right that it shouldn't be used flippantly -- especially if you ever plan on sharing the code with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't give the `display` as parameter to the `pow` function, it expects a number. and don't forget to set the display.

```
   powF = frame(self, BOTTOM)
   button(powF, LEFT, 'pow', lambda w=display: w.set(pow(float(w.get()),2)))
```